# Subdomain authentication with Devise and Simple Token Authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I'm having trouble figuring out how to properly subdomain my api. I want it to live at api.mydomain.com. I've added `127.0.0.1    api.mydomain.com` in my hosts file.
I'm stuck with how to structure the authentication module, and how to actually get it to work.

I'm using [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) with the [Simple Token Authentication](https://github.com/gonzalo-bulnes/simple_token_authentication) gem.

My controller folder structure is as follows:

```
├── controllers
    ├── api
    │   ├── api_controller.rb
    │   └── v1
    │       ├── emails_controller.rb
    │       ├── entries_controller.rb
    │       ├── exception_controller.rb
    │       ├── registrations_controller.rb
    │       ├── sessions_controller.rb
    │       └── timelines_controller.rb
    ├── application_controller.rb
    ├── concerns
```

And my route scheme:

```
namespace :api, path: '/', constraints: {subdomain: 'api'} do
      namespace :v1 do
        devise_for :users, :skip => [:sessions, :registrations, :passwords]

        devise_scope :user do
          post 'login' => 'sessions#create', :as => :login
          delete 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy', :as => :logout
          post 'register' => 'registrations#create', :as => :register
          delete 'delete_account' => 'registrations#destroy', :as => :delete_account
        end

        resources :timelines do
          resources :entries
        end
    end
  end
```

My custom SessionsController is defined as:

```
class API::V1::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
   ...
end
```

and so is my custom registrations controller.
But when running my test:

```
it 'creates a new user with correct credentials' do
            post 'http://api.mydomain.com:3000/v1/register', format: :json, :user => {email: 'user@test.com', password: 'TestPass123', password_confirmation: 'TestPass123', username: 'testuser'}

            ...
end
```

I get the following error:

```
Failure/Error: post 'http://api.mydomain.com:3000/v1/register', format: :json, :user => {email: 'user@test.com', password: 'TestPass123', password_confirmation: 'TestPass123', username: 'testuser'}
 AbstractController::ActionNotFound:
   Could not find devise mapping for path "/v1/register".
   This may happen for two reasons:

   1) You forgot to wrap your route inside the scope block. For example:

     devise_scope :user do
       get "/some/route" => "some_devise_controller"
     end

   2) You are testing a Devise controller bypassing the router.
      If so, you can explicitly tell Devise which mapping to use:

      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
```

Am I even doing this right? Are you supposed to version your authentication? Suggestions to a different solution is more than welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that this line

`devise_for :users, :skip => [:sessions, :registrations, :passwords]`

needs to be outside the namespace block like such:

```
   devise_for :users, :skip => [:sessions, :registrations, :passwords]
   constraints subdomain: 'api' do
    namespace :api, path: '/', defaults: { format: :json } do
      namespace :v1 do
        devise_scope :user do
          post 'login' => 'sessions#create', :as => :login
          delete 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy', :as => :logout
          post 'register' => 'registrations#create', :as => :register
          delete 'delete_account' => 'registrations#destroy', :as => :delete_account
        end

        resources :timelines do
          resources :entries
        end
    end
  end
end
```